# How to send data from Datalist using button to different pages in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, button, datalist

This is the design page that contains my datalist. Also a button within datalist which will pass data to another page on clicking.

**Product.aspx**

```
    <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Home.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Products.aspx.cs" Inherits="GasBookingPortal.Products" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
        <style type="text/css">
        </style>
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
      <asp:DataList ID="DataListProduct" ItemStyle-Width="500px" ItemStyle-BorderStyle="Solid" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatLayout="Table" EnableViewState="false">
    <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" Width="500px"></ItemStyle>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
           <img width="100" src='Product_Images/<%# Eval("Product_Image") %>' />

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
                            Product Name
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Product_Name") %>
                        </td>
                        <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
                            Product ID
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("P_ID") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
                            Product Price
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Product_Price") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
                            Product Category
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Product_Category") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
                            Product Description
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <%# Eval("Product_Description") %>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border-width: 1px">
   <asp:Button ID="btnBook" runat="server" Text="BOOK" OnClick="btnBook_Click"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>  
    </asp:Content>
```

This is the code behind. Here I want to write button click event for redirection. Also want to pass few data. I don't know what exactly I have to use for example `datalist_itemcommand` event or `button_click` event to redirect into another page and to pass data from datalist.

**Product.aspx.cs**

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.UI;
    using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.Web.Configuration;

    namespace GasBookingPortal
    {
        public partial class Products : System.Web.UI.Page
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gbpcon"].ToString());
            protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {

                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    GetDataFromTable();
                    BindDataToDataList();
                }

            }

            public void GetDataFromTable()
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Product_Image,Product_Name,Product_Price,P_ID,Product_Category,Product_Description from Product", con);
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                da.Fill(ds, "table_product");
                DataTable dt = ds.Tables["table_product"];

                //Session["Product_Category"] = dt.Rows[0]["Product_Category"].ToString();
                Session["da"] = da;
                Session["dt"] = dt;
            }
            public void BindDataToDataList()
            {
                DataListProduct.DataSource = (DataTable)Session["dt"];
                DataListProduct.DataBind();
            }

            protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Response.Redirect("PaymentGateway.aspx");
            }
        }
    }
```

Question: I want to send `Product_ID`, `Product_Name`, `Product_Price` to another page `Payment.aspx` whenever someone will click on BOOK button within datalist. On clicking BOOK button the Product page should redirect into Payment page alongwith few data. The button within datalist can be any button like normal button, or image button or link button. Please guide me how to do this. Trying to solve this problem since last 4 days.

Please tell me how to do this. Will be very grateful.
I have tried with all possible ways from google and youtube but none of them worked.

Comment: please ask a question with less code.

Comment: Can you solve this problem?

Comment: yes use to bind your data like `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"ColumnName")`

Comment: my problem not lies with that.. please try to understand my problem. Thank you.

Comment: wait I will provide a solution.

Comment: okay.. will wait. :)

Answer (score 0):

tried...?

```
Session["Product_ID"] = Product_ID; 
Session["Product_Name"] = Product_Name;
Session["Product_Price"] = Product_Price; Response.Redirect("PaymentGateway.aspx");
```

Comment: within button_click event?

Comment: public void GetDataFromTable()
        {
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select Product_Image,Product_Name,Product_Price,P_ID,Product_Category,Product_Description from Product", con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds, "table_product");

Comment: DataTable dt = ds.Tables["table_product"];

            Session["ProductID"] = dt.Rows[0]["P_ID"].ToString();
            Session["ProductName"] = dt.Rows[0]["Product_Name"].ToString();
            Session["ProductPrice"] = dt.Rows[0]["Product_Price"].ToString();
            Session["da"] = da;
            Session["dt"] = dt;
        }

Comment: protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            Response.Redirect("PaymentGateway.aspx");
        }

Comment: Tried above codes but didn't worked.. Main problem is on clicking button its staying in same page. not redirecting at all.

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.  **Flaggers / reviewers:** [For code-only answers such as this one, downvote, don't delete!](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260413/2747593)

Answer (score 0):

In your ***.aspx code** bind your data like `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"P_ID") %>` instead of `<%# Eval("P_ID") %>` to identify your each column uniquely in code-behind.

**Code-Behind:**

```
protected void btnBook_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // get clicked item of datalist
    DataListItem dli = (sender as Button).NamingContainer as DataListItem;

    // access clecked data from datalist
    string id = DataBinder.Eval(dli, "P_ID").ToString();
    string name = DataBinder.Eval(dli, "P_name").ToString();
    // ... other fields

    string sendingData = id + "," + name;

    // send data using query string
    Response.Redirect("PaymentGateway.aspx?data="+sendingData);
}
```

**Payment.aspx page:** Access data from query string like:

```
string data = Request.QueryString["data"];
string[] dArr = data.Split(',');

string id = dArr[0]+"";
string name = dArr[1] + "";
// ... other fields
```

**Edit:** For image use asp control:

```
<asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" ImageUrl='Product_Images/<%# Eval("Product_Image") %>' />
```

### Edit 2: Another solution is:

Add product id and other values as `CommandArgument` to your button:

```
<asp:Button ID="btnBook" runat="server" Text="BOOK" OnClick="btnBook_Click" 
            CommandArgument='<%# Eval("P_ID") %>'/>
```

In button's `OnClick` method get value(s) from `CommandArgument` and store in Session `DATA`:

```
Button btn = sender as Button;
Session["DATA"] = btn.CommandArgument.ToString();
Response.Redirect("PaymentGateway.aspx");
```

And, finally get data from session anywhere an your project files/pages:

```
string sessionData = (string)Session["DATA"];
```

Comment: what to write about first <tr> product image ?

Comment: not happening bro.. on clicking book button it's redirecting to same page.. same results like before.

Comment: @Saakey7 see my edit 2 there is another solution for your problem and sorry for late reply!